# How to translate a sentence that contains is/are being +pp

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Ich lerne Deutsch und meine aktuelles Kenntnisniveau ist B1.

Ich möchte bitte wissen, wie man kann die folgenden Sätze übersetzt.

> Ukrain is being fought against by the Russian soldiers.

Comment: Das Problem scheint die Übersetzung der Verlaufsform zu sein, dazu gibt es schon viele Fragen, zum Beispiel [diese](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/74136/1696).

Comment: Clarify the question please: what's your attempt and what is concerning about it in your eyes?

Comment: It's a good idea to ask the question in the language you're most comfortable in since the custom is to answer in the language the question was asked. It helps to keep the title and and question in the same language so there is no confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Kurze Antwort:

> Die Ukraine wird von russischen Soldaten bekämpft.

---

### Im Detail:

Das ist ein ziemlich schwieriges grammatisches Konstrukt, von dem ich nicht glaube, dass es zum Niveau B1 passt.

Bei diesem Satz handelt es sich um eine Passiv-Konstruktion. Das heißt, dass das Subjekt nicht das Agens (also der Täter) sondern das Patients (der Erdulder/Erleider) ist.

Der Kern jedes Satzes ist das Verb. Das Verb des vorliegenden Satzes ist eine Form von *»to fight«* und das ist auf Deutsch *»kämpfen«.* Der englische Satz enthält zusätzlich noch die Präposition *»against«,* die auf Deutsch *»gegen«* heißt, und zusammen mit *»to fight«* so verwendet wird:

> to fight against someone = gegen jemanden kämpfen

Aber der englische Satz ist - wie schon erwähnt - ein Passiv-Satz. Die Ukraine führt den Kampf nicht aus, sondern muss den Kampf über sich ergehen lassen.

Im Deutschen kann man eigentlich nur dann einen Satz als Passiv-Satz konstruieren, wenn das Verb ein Akkusativobjekt hat, wie in diesem Beispiel:

> Aktiv: Die Prinzessin küsst den Frosch.
> Passiv: Der Frosch wird von der Prinzessin geküsst.

Das Akkusativobjekt des Aktiv-Satzes (*den Frosch*) wird zum Subjekt des Passiv-Satzes (*der Frosch*), das Subjekt des Aktivsatzes wird zu einem optionalen Satzteil, der das Agens des Passivsatzes ist und von der Konstruktiuon her einem Präpositionalobjekt aber auch einer adverbialen Bestimmung ähnelt.

Das Problem ist nun aber, dass das Verb *kämpfen* kein Akkusativobjekt erlaubt. Das wäre falsch:

> *falsch:* Walter kämpft den Feind.

Das Verb *kämpfen* kann aber mit einem Präpositionalobjekt die gewünschte Aussage machen, und dabei wird die Präposition *gegen* verwendet:

> *richtig:* Walter kämpft **gegen den Feind.**

Aber der Teil *»gegen den Feind«* ist kein Akkusativobjekt, sondern ein Präpositionalobjekt. Der Teil *»den Feind«* ist zwar ein Akkusativobjekt, aber es gehört nicht zum Verb, sondern ist die Ergänzung der Präposition *»gegen«* im Präpositionalobjekt *»gegen den Feind«.*

Das heißt: Das Verb *kämpfen* hat kein Akkusativobjekt, und daher kann man aus einem Aktiv-Satz, der dieses Verb enthält, auch nicht so einfach einen Passiv-Satz machen.

##### Aber es gibt einen Trick:

Im Deutschen gibt es das Verb *»bekämpfen«.* Es hat eine Bedeutung, die der von *»kämpfen«* sehr ähnlich ist, und es wird mit einem Akkusativobjekt verwendet:

> Der Gärtner bekämpft das Unkraut.

Im Satz *»Walter kämpft gegen Simon«* sind Walter und Simon gleichwertige Kontrahenten, und der Ausgang des Kampfes ist ungewiss. Die Bedeutung von *»Walter bekämpft Simon«* ist eine andere. Dieser Satz sagt aus, dass Walter Simon vernichten, oder zumindest unterdrücken will. Simon steht nicht auf derselben Stufe wie Walter.

Aber man verwendet dieses Wort trotzdem, um Sätze, die im Aktiv mit *»kämpfen«* gebildet werden, in eine passive Form zu bringen:

- Ursprüngliche Aktiv-Form ohne Akkusativ-Objekt:

  > Walter kämpft gegen Simon.
- Aktiv-Form mit einem ähnlichem Verb und einem Akkusativ-Objekt:

  > Walter bekämpft Simon.
- Passiv-Form:

  > Simon wird von Walter bekämpft.

**Und jetzt wissen wir alles, was wir benötigen, um den englischen Satz zu übersetzen:**

- Ursprünglicher englischer Satz:

  > Ukrain is being fought against by the Russian soldiers.
- Aktiv-Form des englischen Satzes:

  > Russian soldiers are fighting against the Ukrain.
- Deutsche Übersetzung des Aktiv-Satzes:

  > Russische Soldaten kämpfen gegen die Ukraine.
- Trick: anderes Verb, um ein Akkusativobjekt zu erhalten:

  > Russische Soldaten bekämpfen die Ukraine.
- Passiv-Form des letzten Satzes:

  > Die Ukraine wird von russischen Soldaten bekämpft.

Comment: Das ist kein "Trick" (Verarsche?). Es ergibt sich aus dem (mehr oder weniger) direkten Zusammenhang zwischen *be-* und englisch *by, be-*.

Answer (score 2):

> is/are being + past participle

That's present continous tense passive voice in English. For passive voice German also tells apart ongoing and completed actions.

Use conjugated *werden* + Partizip II for ongoing passive actions. It's called *Vorgangspassiv.* You may also include an adverb as *gerade* that also marks an action as ongoing.

> Ukraine is being fought against by the Russian soldiers

*Die Ukraine **wird** (gerade) von den russischen Soldaten **bekämpft.***

You may also want to reorder to make that *gerade* the topic to point out the ongoing nature of the action even more:

*Gerade wird die Ukraine von den russischen Soldaten bekämpft.*

This implies the question “Who's next?”

Comment: Warum antwortest du auf Englisch? Die Frage wurde auf Deutsch gestellt.

Comment: Die Überschrift und damit die Grammatikfrage war auf Englisch. Im deutschen Text ging es hingegen um einen konkreten Übersetzungswunsch.

Answer (score 0):

> Ich möchte bitte wissen, wie man kann die folgenden Sätze übersetzt.

Das wirkliche Problem in dieser Frage scheint Satzstellung zu sein. Das andere haben Huber und Janka schon erklärt.

Relativsätze sind in Verbletztstellung zu formulieren. Das gilt auch für eingebetete Fragen

> *wie man den* [= dativ singular] *folgenden Satz übersetzen kann*

Die übliche Lehrmethode zur Übersetzung des Präsenz Progressiv ist nämlich *am sein tun* oder *am tun sein*, gehobener *in Begriff dieses zu tun sein* und ähnliche Adverbialphrasen. Die Wortwörtliche Übersetzung läuft somit ins leere.

Übrigens ist *am* in dem Zusammenhang sicherlich mit engl. *by* und dementsprechend *be-* zu vergleichen. Dies sollte eigentlich auf die erste Person beschränkt sein. *M-* wie *inmitten* und dazugehörig *mit* ("with") ist davon aber gar nicht strikt zu trennen, weil *-m- prehistorisch den Rektus markiert, woraus einst *-n-* wurde (weswegen es in der Grammatik konsequent *Rektum* heißen müsste?)

> * Die Ukraine ist im Kampf mit den Russen.

Einfacher verhält es sich im Sport, wo der Schiedsrichter sein Auto sein Standort bekannt sein dürfte.

> Ukraine gegen Russland

um Direktion der Kausalität wegen

> der Ukraine Krieg von wegen Russland

Das passt dann auch hervorragend mit engl. *to wage war*, zufällig, verblüffender Weise, müsste also richtig **wägen* heißen, wobei die Großschreibung des Nomens nicht eindeutig ist.

---

Sicher ist das sicherlich nicht. Wie dem auch sei, die beiden Antworten über mir betreffend *bekämpfen* sind falsch. Das sagt man über Ungeziefer oder Armut, wenn die Rechtfertigung nicht in Frage steht.

Allenfalls gilt *sich im Kampf be-finden*, wie schon bei Orwell

> Eurasien befindet sich im Kampf mit Ozeanien